# Bring UIView to the front

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

1. I have a TabManViewController (that you can find in this repository https://github.com/uias/Tabman ) which embeds 3 Viewcontrollers.
2. In one of this embedded ViewControllers I have one UIView that is draggable with a UIPanGestureRecogniser.
3. When I drag it I see that it goes behind the TabMan Bar, while I want it to go over it.
4. I tried this snippet of code in the viewController that embeds the view but It doesn't work.

   self.view.bringSubviewToFront(cardView)

How can I bring the view above everything else?

Comment: That will bring the view to the front of that view controller. Can you add that ViewController so it's above the others?

Comment: I actually need that viewcontroller to be behind tab bar but I only need the UIView inside it to be in top of everything

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to either

1- The tabBarController' view

2- Window's view

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace "view" in below code with the parent view of cardview

self.view.bringSubviewToFront(cardView)

```
self.yourCardview'sParentView.bringSubviewToFront(cardView)
```

Comment: I tried it, cause "view" in below code is the viewcontroller parent view,  but it doesn't work because parent view has the tab bar inside it and I need the card view to go over this bar